# How do I successfully deploy shared printers via GPO? Windows 10 Pro + Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, print-server, shared-printers

I keep getting a GPO error 0x80070bcb on my Windows 10 Pro clients when trying to install a Brother shared network printer.  Apparently this error means it can't find a driver (or can't install it).

1. The printer is shared from a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, which is also a DC in my domain.
2. I have downloaded the latest driver from the Brother website, which claims that the driver is WHQL Certified.
3. I have installed both the 64-bit and 32-bit version of the driver to the print server.
4. I have enabled Point and Print Restrictions via GPO, and specified the aforementioned print server as an authorized source of drivers.  Additionally I have disabled warnings when installing a new printer (warning only is enabled for updating a driver).
5. Printing works fine from the server.

What else is necessary to overcome this error?

Comment: How you are configuring your GPO processes to map the networked printers? Are you using scripts, GP Preferences, what settings and values are you using, and is this just an issue with the Brother printer or with all printers?

Comment: the printers are mapped as simple Shared Printers in User Config -> Control Panel -> Printers.  I'm not using any special settings.  I have the same problem with other printers, unless I use the default generic drivers built-in to Windows Server (probably because the same drivers are built in to Windows 10, so no downloading-of-new-drivers-from-the-server has to occur)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Cumulative update for Windows 10 KB3176493 breaks the deployment of printers via GPO to Windows 10 clean builds. I uninstalled this update and have successfully deployed my printers again to my clients.

Comment: All my Windows 10 computers are running Anniversary edition (14393) and all available updates.  I would like a solution that does not involve backtracking.

Comment: There are multiple bugs with the anniversary edition already. I wouldn't recommend installing a major update like this in a production environment the moment Microsoft releases an update. I was just advising of my experiences of what broke the printer deployment in my environment. I used WSUS to remove the above mentioned KB update until Microsoft resolves it.

Comment: I found this very recent thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/030ee94a-047d-460a-bc39-52351a199364/kb3163912-breaks-point-and-print-restrictions-gpo-settings?forum=winserverGP which points to KB3163912 as being the source of the problem.  Either way, looks like the fault is on Microsoft's end.  :/